# How to edit File object in javascript

Tags: angularjs, file

My drag-dropped file looks like the below:

•
[File(1351429)]
1.  0:File(1351429)
1.  lastModified:1524514419721
2.  lastModifiedDate:Mon Apr 23 2018 13:13:39 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) {}
3.  name:xxxxxx
4.  size:xxxxxxx
5.  type:xxxxx
6.  webkitRelativePath:""
7.  **proto**:File
2.  length:1
3.  **proto**:Array(0)

I want to modify the file type. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

This looks like a Dropzone.JS file object. If that's the case, and you are using jQuery, you can edit the file object on the `change` or `addedfile` event like so:

```
// Target your Dropzone Element Id -- listen for the 'addedfile' event
$('#dropzone').on('addedfile', function(event) {
    console.log("files: ", this.files)

    // 'this' holds the files array -- access the files by index
    var file = this.files[0];

    // You can get the latest file added to the array this way
    var mostRecentFile = this.files[this.files.length - 1]

    // Now you can modify the file object
    file.name = "MeowMix.txt";
    file.type = "text/plain" ;
})
```

### Clarity

Please make sure to specify application details (plugins being used, frameworks, libraries, etc.) in your question so we can better assist answering them!

### Reference

-- [Dropzone.JS - AddedFile Event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-addedfile)

Answer (score -1):

I am using ng-file-uploader and the solution to the problem is:

file = file.slice(0, file.size, "application/xxxxxxxx.ppxml+xml");

This will take care of modifying the content type of the file!